# What is the sorting for ties on the Winter Bash leader board?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016, winterbash-leaderboard

[image: leader board]

There are four of us that got all the hats. However I'm slightly baffled by the order we appear. I'm wondering what the order is where there is a tie (like the four of us in first place).

Some things I know it is *not*:

- First to get 41 hats
- Last to get the 41st hat
- Alphabetically by user name
- Most hats on one site
- Reputation

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is a WB id, like the one that chooses which where in the world it is

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn it was "First to get 41 hats" before it ended.

Comment: Pure speculation, but it appears to be alphabetical among those which link to Stack Overflow profiles.

Comment: if that is the case, I'm changing my name to AaaaaaA before next Winter Bash...

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara um no it isn't "ale**c**" comes before "ale**x**"

Comment: Hmm, true. Unless capitalization plays in a very strange way.

Comment: Is it the same every time you view the page?

Comment: I think it's sorted by coolest avatar.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On the network-wide leaderboard, the secondary sort is by the number of total hats across all sites (as opposed to distinct hats). You can see that number in the tool tip if you hover over the hat count in the list. Alexander O'Mara has 105, alecxe has 98, Eran has 92, and you have 73.

On the site-specific leaderboards, the secondary sort is arbitrary.

Comment: Nice feature, that tooltip. *38 distinct hats across all sites, 444 hats total*