# Is there any way to see my total hat count across the entire network?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I've earned the same hat on multiple Stack Exchange sites but I am unable to find any way to see total count of all of the hats I've gotten. Is there any way to see a total count of the hats I have?

If possible just like this:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Answer don't address the problem. Scrolling down to count is so painful.

[image]

Comment: No, you have to count manually

Comment: Answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159381/how-can-i-see-the-hats-i-have-earned-across-all-of-se) might be still useful. :)

Comment: You have 105 hats! :P But, really, just 9.

Comment: @Catija yep :D :P

Comment: I try to fight against spam so I got so many hat on SE  with help of charcoal but unable to see total count of hat. So I ask question . If you don't like my  idea feel free to down vote. I know how down vote work on meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on a computer with a mouse, you can look at your own entry in the [network leaderboard](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) (if you're logged in to the Winter Bash site, it will be shown at the top) and hover over the hat count. The tooltip will tell you how many hats you've earned in total.

The Winter Bash philosophy mostly considers a hat only once, even if it's earned on multiple sites, that's why this information is a bit hidden, but it's there (and it's used for [secondary sorting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289548/what-is-the-sorting-for-ties-on-the-winter-bash-leader-board/289562#289562) on the network leaderboard).

Answer (score 3):

## The snowflake menu tells all:

> [image: Snowflake icon and dropdown menu]

---

#### If you've earned too many hats to eyeball the count, my hat's off to you!

Comment: The OP has earned 95 of the Still Fresh hats alone. Not really countable in the dropdown. :)

Comment: And here I thought the images in the question were representative of @Shree's hat count. *tips hat to @Shree*

Comment: Well, now that the question has been edited, my answer and comment don't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the total count of all hats combined, balpha's solution is going to get that for you.

If you want to see the count of each hat you have, you can do that in your hat box:

[image: Shree's hat box with Still Fresh hat selected, showing the sites that it's achieved on]

When you click on the hat, it tells you which site you've earned it on. If you've earned it on more than seven sites, it tells you "and *n* other sites". So, by adding 7 to *n*, you get your total for that specific hat. In your case, *n* = 88, so you have 95 Still Fresh hats. Of your other hats, you've currently earned one each of six of them and two each of two of them, for a grand total of 105 hats as of writing.