# What do the numbers on the Winter Bash leaderboard mean?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winterbash-leaderboard

I thought that they represented the rank of the person by the number of hats they have collected. The numbers "jump" however, they do not follow an unbroken order:

[image]

There are also really big gaps:

[image]

#### What do these number mean? Are they supposed to be like this?

Comment: Wow, See "U9-Forward", i am 42nd rank, but on SO, 4th rank.

Comment: Only two more down votes....I've never looked for down votes before.

Comment: What ya mean? are you talking to me?

Comment: @U9-Forward: No, I wasn't talking to you : ). I need two more down votes to earn a secret hat. I was just saying that it is odd to want down votes; that only happens during WB.

Comment: I know :-), Sun Wukong, right? :-)

Comment: @U9-Forward: Right. +10/-4 just one downvote to go...

Comment: You earned it :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those numbers are indeed the ranking of the people, based on the number of hats they have collected.

[image]

As you can see, there's two people with 29 hats, so they're sharing first place. That means the people with 28 hats have two people above them on the list, so they share 3rd place, and then we move on to the fifth entry on that list, because there's 4 people with more hats than them...

Answer (score 8):

They are called as [Standard competition ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_(%221224%22_ranking))

> ... each item's ranking number is 1 plus the number of items ranked above it. This ranking strategy is frequently adopted for competitions, as it means that if two (or more) competitors tie for a position in the ranking, the position of all those ranked below them is unaffected (i.e., a competitor only comes second if exactly one person scores better than them, third if exactly two people score better than them, fourth if exactly three people score better than them, etc.).

So if two persons are received 5th rank means the 6th rank will not be available. And the next rank value is 7th.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are. People with the same number of hats are tied for x-th place. E.g. Monica and David are tied for 5th place, so there is no 6th place. There is some kind of tiebreaker for the *total* number of hats earned, this matters for the order but not for the 'rank' in the leaderboard.

Since there are more people with a low number of hats, the gaps will be much larger lower down the list.

Answer (score 2):

> What do the numbers on the Winter Bash leaderboard mean?

The ranking is based on ***different*** hats collected, with *totals* hidden.

Last year the "*Rank*" was determined by two factors: 1. Different hat types **+** 2. Total hats owned.

[For example](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network): user "alecxe" has **72** hats **total** and user "eLRuLL" has only **56** hats total - but both have **29** ***different*** hats. Thus alecxe is first. In the event of a tie time might be used to determine whom is first.

See: [What is the sorting for ties on the Winter Bash leader board?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289562/282094):

> On the network-wide leaderboard, the secondary sort is by the number of total hats across all sites (as opposed to distinct hats). You can see that number in the tool tip if you hover over the hat count in the list.
>
> ...
>
> On the site-specific leaderboards, the secondary sort is arbitrary.
>
> answered Jan 9 '17 at 8:31
>   balpha♦

This year the same system might be used, or alternatively we will have to wait for balpha to answer.