# Why are ranks not uniform on Winter Bash leaderboard?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, winter-bash, rankings

Why are ranks not uniform on the Winter Bash leaderboard? Is this a bug?

Network-wide leaderboard:
[image]

Stack Overflow leaderboard:
[image]

---

**Edit:**

So it is [Standard competition ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_(%221224%22_ranking)) (Thanks to Suraj Rao).
But what is the rationale behind using this over other ranking systems? Also, is this used over the entire SE network?

Comment: Why not? It’s one of the most natural solutions for a problem of zero importance. Does that really require a *rationale*?

Comment: So many downvotes...

Comment: Duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320926/282094

Comment: Yes... :-o  Missed that

Answer (score 11):

It looks like [Standard competition ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking) or 1224 ranking is applied on the leaderboard where if multiple folks are ranked the same, the next spots are skipped.

> In competition ranking, items that compare equal receive the same ranking number, and then a gap is left in the ranking numbers. The number of ranking numbers that are left out in this gap is one less than the number of items that compared equal. Equivalently, each item's ranking number is 1 plus the number of items ranked above it.

This doesn't look like a bug.

Comment: I have updated the question.